# How to search/find a words/data (in this case "Country ") from a table ( api data) with a search box?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I want to search country names with that text box, find the specific data from that massive list of names, and show that the only data to the user, not all the data. Please help me to do that. I have no idea how to do this.

```js
// api section 




const tbody = document.querySelector('#tbody');

const getdata = async () => {
    const endpoint = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary",
        response = await fetch(endpoint),
        data = await response.json(),
        Countries = data.Countries;





    Countries.forEach(countryObj => {
        let { Country, NewConfirmed, TotalConfirmed, NewDeaths, TotalDeaths, NewRecovered, TotalRecovered, Date } = countryObj;
        tbody.innerHTML += `<tr>
        <td>${Country}</td>
        <td>${NewConfirmed}</td>
        <td>${TotalConfirmed}</td>
        <td>${NewDeaths}</td>
        <td>${TotalDeaths}</td>
        <td>${NewRecovered}</td>
        <td>${TotalRecovered}</td>
        <td>${Date}</td>
    </tr>`;
    });



}


getdata();




<---------------------------- search box function------------->


 // Don't know how to do it.....help me ....Thanks in advance :)
```

```html
<!--------------search Box & search button ------- -->


<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder=" Search Country " >

    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit">



<!----------------data table--------------- -->

  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Country</th>
        <th scope="col">NewConfirmed</th>
        <th scope="col">TotalConfirmed</th>
        <th scope="col">NewDeaths</th>
        <th scope="col">TotalDeaths</th>
        <th scope="col">NewRecovered</th>
        <th scope="col">TotalRecovered</th>
        <th scope="col">Last Updated on</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">



    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I want to search country names with that text box, find the specific data from that massive list of names, and show that the only data to the user, not all the data. Please help me to do that.

Comment: What is already working with all that code? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: API is working, I can see the fetched data in a table format but now I want a search box for searching data from inside the table, like this website ...they use a search box to search among the data. https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/  @NicoHaase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that is actually needed here is a way to 'search' the data and display those results. This can be done using the `filter()` method for an array.

Essentially, you just need to store your data in a global variable that can be filtered later, based on user input. Also, I usually make it a point to separate certain functionality, like displaying data. So instead of displaying the country data inside of the `getData()` function, I would create a separate function that just filters and displays data. This way you can call it after you fetch the data, and then call that same function each time you search (rather than have repeated code that displays countries in the table).

```js
let countriesData = [];

const getdata = async () => {
  const endpoint = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary",
        response = await fetch(endpoint),
        data = await response.json();

  countriesData = data.Countries;
  _DisplayCountries();
}

const _DisplayCountries = (c = "") => {
  let tbody = document.querySelector("#tbody");
  tbody.innerHTML = ``;
  countriesData.filter(country => country.Country.toLowerCase().includes(c.toLowerCase())).forEach(result => {
    tbody.innerHTML += `<tr>
        <td>${result.Country}</td>
        <td>${result.NewConfirmed}</td>
        <td>${result.TotalConfirmed}</td>
        <td>${result.NewDeaths}</td>
        <td>${result.TotalDeaths}</td>
        <td>${result.NewRecovered}</td>
        <td>${result.TotalRecovered}</td>
        <td>${result.Date}</td>
    </tr>`;
  });
}

getdata();

document.querySelector("#mySubmit").addEventListener("click", e => {
  _DisplayCountries(document.querySelector("#myInput").value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder=" Search Country ">
<input type="submit" id="mySubmit" value="Search" class="submit">


  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Country</th>
        <th scope="col">NewConfirmed</th>
        <th scope="col">TotalConfirmed</th>
        <th scope="col">NewDeaths</th>
        <th scope="col">TotalDeaths</th>
        <th scope="col">NewRecovered</th>
        <th scope="col">TotalRecovered</th>
        <th scope="col">Last Updated on</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
  </table>
```

**NOTES**

There are definitely a lot of different ways to `filter()` the data and I opted for a very simple `includes()` method. I also added `toLowerCase()` to the country and the search string to make it case-insensitive, but I understand there are several ways to do this as well.

```
let regex = new RegExp(c, "i");
countriesData.filter(country => country.Country.match(regex))
```

That for example would also return a list of search results that are case-insensitive.